# How to download styles via Chrome debugger API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to get styles with exact, not computed values for my extension. I can use `document.styleSheets` in some cases, but in case when css styles hosted on other domain, I am getting CORS error. I found a way to get those styles with help of `chrome.debugger` API, but having difficulties with implementation:

```
chrome.debugger.attach(debuggeeId, "1.3", () => {
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, "Page.enable", null, (r) => {
        chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, "Page.getResourceTree", null, (res) => {
            // get style URLs from resourceTree object
            const cssResources = getCSSResources(res.frameTree.resources);
            for(let url of cssResources) {
                chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, "Page.getResourceContent", {frameId: toString(tabId), url: url}, (resp) => {
                    console.log(resp) /// return undefined
                })
            }
        })
    })
})
```

For some reasons I am getting `undefined` from `Page.getResourceContent`.   Just to clarify, getting `undefined` because of CORS(also works here??) or because of incorrect response to `chrome.debugger` API?

Code below cause the same - no data from request was returned.
[image]

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what's wrong with using the computed styles? How does that that effect your usecase?

Comment: The main purpose of the app is to show exact property units(em, vh), not computed(px) one.

Comment: Gotcha. Lemme think on it.

Comment: Do you happen to have a git repo of your code I could clone so I don't have to spin up an extension from scratch?

Comment: Part of the problem is that you haven't included the code for the `getCSSResources` function in the question. From what I'm seeing so far, `Page.getResourceTree` doesn't return stylesheets for all pages. Try it on this very page and you'll see.

Comment: @Geuis, you can play with code here:
https://github.com/IvanSoputnyak/example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see is that `frameId` is an internal id of the frame which you can get from res.frameTree.frame.id, it's not related to tabId.

Might process all frames recursively, at least of the same origin, and use the modern syntax:

```js
chrome.debugger.attach(debuggeeId, '1.3', async () => {
  const send = (cmd, params = null) =>
    new Promise(resolve =>
      chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, cmd, params, resolve));
  await send('Page.enable');
  const {frameTree} = await send('Page.getResourceTree');
  const frameQueue = [frameTree];
  const results = [];
  for (const {frame, childFrames, resources} of frameQueue) {
    frameQueue.push(...childFrames);
    const frameId = frame.id;
    for (const {url, type} of resources) {
      if (type === 'Stylesheet') {
        results.push({
          url,
          frameUrl: frame.url,
          ...await send('Page.getResourceContent', {frameId, url}),
        });
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Still no success, but now I am getting error:
```Unchecked runtime.lastError: {"code":-32000,"message":"Agent is not enabled."}``` Did I miss something else?

Comment: I guess I forgot `Page.enable`